# Thousands of succesive joins, need performance in R

Tags: r, performance, join

I need to perform about a thousands of left joins the fastest way possible because I would like to repeat it thousands of times. It takes about 60 secondes to perform about 1000 joins. I'm not happy with that. Anyone sees how can I speed up this computation?

So I got a list of data.frame that I want to join with a data.table by the key id_client. **table0** is a data.table. elements of **list_of_dataframe** are data.frames

Here is my code :

```
setkey(table0,id_client)
for (i in seq(1,length(list_of_dataframe))){
table0=merge(table0,setkey(setDT(list_of_dataframe[[i]]),id_client),
             all.x=TRUE,by.x="id_client",by.y="id_client")
  }
```

Comment: How many rows are you dealing with? In that loop you both set keys and join, how much of the time is taken up by the join? Would it help at all in your use case / be possible to set the keys in advance of the joins?

Comment: Not a lot of rows, between 500 and 5000. I'l gonna test your reco

Comment: Maybe you want to do one join on millions of rows, rather than thousands of joins on thousands of rows?

Answer (score 2):

If the whole set can fit into memory, you'll be better off concatenating the `list_of_dataframe` and then doing just one merge.

This code just sets up a list of 1000 data frames each with 2250 rows:

```r
library(pacman)
p_load(data.table, foreach, tictoc)    
size.df = 2250
num.df = 1000

foreach(i=seq(1,size.df*num.df,size.df)) %do% {
  data.frame(id_unique=i:(i+size.df-1),
             id_client=sample(i:(i+size.df-1), size.df, replace=TRUE),
             value=rnorm(size.df))
} -> list_of_dataframe

table0 = data.table(id_client=1:(size.df*num.df))
```

Here is the concatenation and the merge, which take about 12s on my machine:

```r
> tic()
> merge(table0, do.call('rbind', list_of_dataframe),
        all.x=TRUE, by='id_client') -> result
> toc()
12.178 sec elapsed
```

Note that a unique id column was added to allow for non-distinct id_client.  You'd have to handle this some way or other.  You can reshape as necessary if you want the duplicates as columns rather than rows.

```r
> head(result)
   id_client id_unique      value
1:         1       725 -0.8468212
2:         2        NA         NA
3:         3      1066 -0.1352698
4:         3      1906 -0.5246030
5:         4        NA         NA
6:         5      1732 -0.1328604
```

If it's not possible to fit everything in memory, then `foreach` with a `.combine/.multicombine` could be used to process and merge chunks (possibly in parallel).